# show all tasks of each person in TODO list

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to ask my question more clearly because I think that people didn't understand me:

I have an application of: TODO LIST in RUBY ON RAILS.

I want to create something like:

[image]

I succeeded to create the first part (Tasks Workers), but only the: name, num_of_tasks, num_tasks_left.

now I want to create the: "Show Tasks".

when the user pressed the link of: "tasks", he will be direct to a page with all of the tasks (with options for edit and delete).

for example, if the user pressed the link of "tasks" in the line of a person with a name of "Alon", he would direct to a page that will show him the second part (Tasks Of Alon).

what should I need to add in order to get this output? for meantime I have a tasks_controller.

before I explain another thing, I want to let you know about the first part (Tasks Workers). there is a variable: name. in each row, I print the variable name (he passes all the database).

Why can't I do the next steps?

1) add a variable in tasks_controller:

```
def show_tasks
    @tasks = Task.where(:name => params[:name])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @tasks }
    end
end
```

2) define: show_tasks.html.erb that will show the second part(Tasks Of X)

3) create a link in index.html.erb by:

```
<td><%= link_to 'tasks', show_tasks_path(name) %></td>
```

and then for each line, the 'name' variable will be sent to show_tasks.html.erb.

thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use nested resources. Google can help you to find documentation about it.
(or click here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources )

Basically, you would have 2 controllers in your case:
TasksController and WorkersController (or TaskWorkersController)

Your routes.rb should contain something like this:

```
# routes.rb
resources :workers do
  resources :tasks
end
```

This will generates the Paths & Helpers you need. Refer to the doc, if you can't find how to do it I can help you a little but it shouldn't be too hard ;)

**Some tips:**

Your `show_tasks` action will become the `index` action of the TasksController, which would be like:

```
@tasks = Task.where(worker_id: params[:id]) # works if your declared Task belongs_to Worker
```

Your action where you display all the Workers (Alon, Dan, etc) will be the `index` action of the WorkersController.

Good luck!

Comment: I am trying right now to read and do what you suggested. thank you very much! you let me hope :]]

Comment: How did it go @AlonShmiel ?